# import pymongo works in Python interpreter but not script

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I first installed pymongo using easy_install, that didn't work so I tried with pip and it is still failing.

This is fine in the terminal:

```
Macintosh:etc me$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 14:13:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>>
```

But on line 10 of my script

```
import pymongo
```

throws the following error:

> File "test.py", line 10, >in <module>
>      import pymongo
>   ImportError: No module named pymongo

I'm using the standard Lion builds of Apache and Python. Is there anybody else who has experienced this?

Thanks

EDIT: I should also mention that during install it throws the following error

```
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
Downloading pymongo-2.1.1.tar.gz (199Kb): 199Kb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pymongo

Installing collected packages: pymongo
Running setup.py install for pymongo
building 'bson._cbson' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Ibson -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c bson/_cbsonmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

**************************************************************
WARNING: The bson._cbson extension module could not
be compiled. No C extensions are essential for PyMongo to run,
although they do result in significant speed improvements.

If you are seeing this message on Linux you probably need to
install GCC and/or the Python development package for your
version of Python. Python development package names for popular
Linux distributions include:

RHEL/CentOS: python-devel
Debian/Ubuntu: python-dev

Above is the ouput showing how the compilation failed.
**************************************************************

building 'pymongo._cmessage' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Ibson -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pymongo/_cmessagemodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

**************************************************************
WARNING: The pymongo._cmessage extension module could not
be compiled. No C extensions are essential for PyMongo to run,
although they do result in significant speed improvements.

If you are seeing this message on Linux you probably need to
install GCC and/or the Python development package for your
version of Python. Python development package names for popular
Linux distributions include:

RHEL/CentOS: python-devel
Debian/Ubuntu: python-dev

Above is the ouput showing how the compilation failed.
**************************************************************
```

And then goes on to say

```
Successfully installed pymongo
Cleaning up...
Macintosh:etc me$
```

Very odd.

My sys.path in script is returned as:

['/Library/WebServer/Documents/', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

And in interpreter:

['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLObject-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/FormEncode-1.2.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Comment: Maybe your python path differs in interpretator and in a script? What's your sys.path in both cases?

Comment: Hi Michal, I have edited my post with both outputs. Thanks for yourt time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! Required a path append before importing of the pymongo module

```
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import pymongo
```

Would ideally like to find a way to append this to the pythonpath permanently, but this works for now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the last message says "Successfully installed pymongo" but it obviously failed due to the fact that you don't have gcc installed on your system. You need to do the following:

RHEL/Centos: sudo yum install gcc python-devel
Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev

Then try and install pymongo again.